# Not Getting Bluetooth Authorization Prompt in Xamarin iOS

Tags: bluetooth, ios13, cbcentralmanager

I've had a Xamarin Forms application with a binding to a native bluetooth SDK that's been working beautifully on iOS 12.

On iOS 13 the application crashes.  I'm assuming this is around the new Bluetooth privacy settings.

But despite initialising an instance of CBCentralManager.  I'm not getting the permission prompt.

Also my app in the settings doesn't have an option for bluetooth permissions.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got mine Working today, i fixed it with the new Privacy Entry "NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription" in Info.plist.

So try to add the following lines to your Info.plist:

`<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description for what i need Bluetooth Privs</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description for what i need Bluetooth Privs</string>`

Greetings

Comment: Tnx to you!! I didn't found any mentions about this permission. Where did you found information about this?

Comment: I found it on this Site:
https://blog.estimote.com/post/186160021855/get-ready-for-ios-13-bluetooth-and-location

Comment: In VS 2019 mac , these 2 permissions to be added by text editor in info.plist, otherwise crash persists..Thanks @Sascha.